# How to Compare Hashed Passwords in Golang?

Tags: go, hash, bcrypt, fibers, go-fiber

I was trying to build a login system on Golang's Fiber Farmework and am using Mysql as a database.
I can easily Hash my password but cannot compare if the given password and the stored password is same or not
I've used the

> bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword()
> method.. although i'm giving the exact same password but still it's giving an error.
> please help me

the functions

```
   func hashAndSalt(password string) string {
    pwd := []byte(password)
    hash, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword(pwd, 14)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    return string(hash)
}
func CheckHash(hpass string, pass string) error {
    err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(hpass), []byte(pass))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

The User and Login Type

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    FirstName string `json:"firstname"`
    LastName  string `json:"lastname"`
    Username  string `json:"username"`
    Password  string `json:"-"`
    UserType  string `json:"user_type"`
}
type Log struct {
        Username string `json:"username"`
        Password string `json:"password"`
    }
```

The Create User Function which works fine

```
func CreateUser(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    user := new(User)
    if err := c.BodyParser(user); err != nil {
        return c.Status(500).SendString(err.Error())
    }
    pass := user.Password
    hashedPass := hashAndSalt(pass)
    user.Password = hashedPass
    DB.Create(&user)
    return c.JSON(&user)
}
```

The Login Method...The problem is in the hash checking ...

```
const jwt_secret = "Fahim'sAwesomeSecret"

func Login(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    type Log struct {
        Username string `json:"username"`
        Password string `json:"password"`
    }
    var body Log
    if err := c.BodyParser(&body); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error(), "yayy")
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    username := body.Username
    password := body.Password
    var user User
    DB.Where("username = ?", username).First(&user)
    if username != user.Username {
        return c.Status(200).SendString("User not Found , Maybe wrong Username")
    }

    err := CheckHash(user.Password, password)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return c.Status(500).SendString("Wrong Password")
    }

    token := jwt.New(jwt.SigningMethodHS256)
    claims := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)

    claims["sub"] = user.ID
    claims["exp"] = time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 24 * 7)
    s, err := token.SignedString([]byte(jwt_secret))
    if err != nil {
        return c.SendStatus(fiber.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
    c.Cookie(&fiber.Cookie{
        Name:     "jwt",
        Value:    s,
        Expires:  time.Now().Add(7 * 24 * time.Hour),
        HTTPOnly: true,
        SameSite: "lax",
    })

    return c.Status(fiber.StatusOK).JSON(fiber.Map{
        "token": s,
        "user":  user,
    })
}
```

This is the error i get in the terminial

```
crypto/bcrypt: hashedPassword is not the hash of the given password
```

I've printed the "user.Password" and its giving the alue stored in the database.
so where's the problem?

Comment: Is this a question about fiber (if so then please ask the author of fiber), about how to use package bcrypt (this looks reasonable) or do you wish a code review?

Comment: Taking this down to a [mre] would help get an answer, though the act of doing so will probably answer the question for you.

Comment: In your database you store the hash as a string, but you get is as an []byte. In `CheckHash` you are simply converting the string to []byte but not decoding it in any way. If you are base64 encoding it somewhere during storage, then you should decode it properly instead of just turning the encoded string into bytes

Comment: @caveman do i have to use a variable and do something like this?" newVar := []byte(hpass)" and then use that variable in the function? i tried taht and that didn't work, can you please show me an example of what you just said?

Comment: @caveman i solved it by following the process you said

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing my `User` struct
`Password` from `string` to `byte`

And some few changes according to that